# Need to insert a column in csv and parse current date in it - JREPL.BAT?

Tags: csv, batch-file, command-line-tool, jrepl

I could (thanks to dbenham and its powerful JREPL.BAT) remove header row from CSV File with command

```
jrepl "^(Date,)?.*" "($1?i++:i)?$0:false" /jmatch /jbeg "var i=0" /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

I now need to insert in this csv below the date in first column (here 2016-03-27) for every row and delete last row (total). Would jrepl do this too? Thanks!

```
Report,Begin Date,End Date,Currency,Change Currency
Activity Summary By Account,2016-03-27 00:00:00.000 -0600,2016-03-28 00:00:00.000 -0600,USD,Change Currency

Affiliate,Account,Screen Alias,Total Wagered,Total Payout,Net Win Loss,Percent Payout
FaridZ,BuF,BuFis,1153.00,828.00,325.00,71.81%
JohnX,adel,adel,104.70,71.70,33.00,68.48%
FaridZ,chat00,shat,49065.00,45987.50,3077.50,93.72%
,,Total:,"50,657.70","47,247.20","3,410.50",93.26%
```

Updated: screenshot of final csv output...
[image: Final output]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show what the output should look like.

Comment: Hi, thanks dbenham for looking into this. I am going to add a screenshot (excel) of final output!

Comment: Rather than a screenshot, I think a simple text representation of the output would be better.

Comment: Ok, I already posted the screenshot. Tell me if you need it in text and I will add it. Thanks!

Comment: Screenshot is OK. But the output shown has not deleted the Total: line, so I am confused as to your requirement.

Comment: You are 100% right. I Did the "mockup" too quick and forgot to remove the "total" line which should not be included, rather deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done efficiently with [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044), but the solution is fairly complicated if you want to do everything with a single pass of the input data. I'm not sure that the solution is any simpler than writing a custom JScript or VBS script.

Note that I discovered a minor JREPL.BAT bug while developing this solution, so there is an updated version 3.8 at the link with a few bug fixes.

```
jrepl "^$|^,,Total:,.*|^.*?,(.+?),.*"^
      "i=1;''|false|if(ln==2){dt=$4;$0}else i?$0+','+((i++==1)?'Date':dt):$0"^
      /jmatch /jbeg "var i=0, dt" /t "|" /f test.txt /o output.txt
```

I used line continuation to make the code easier to read.

A bit of explanation of the solution is in order.

`/JBEG` defines a couple of variables that are needed during the find/replace operation.

- `dt` - Holds the captured date string.
- `i` - Used to control whether anything is appended:

  - if `i`=0 then no change
  - if `i`=1 then append the `Date` header
  - else append `dt`

I used `/JMATCH` along with the `/T` option with `|` as a delimiter. The `/T` option is similar to the unix tr command. For each delimited search in the find string, there is a corresponding JScript expression in the replacement string.

- **$1 search** `^$` - Looks for an empty line
  **replace** `i=1;''` - Triggers `i` so that subsequent non-empty lines have the date column appended. The replacement value for this line is an empty string.
- **$2 search** `^,,Total:,.*` - Looks for the final Total line
  **replace** `false` - Prevents the total line from being printed
- **$3 search** `^.*?,(.+?),.*` - Looks for a line with at least 3 fields, capturing the 2nd field in `$4`
  **replace** `if(ln==2){dt=$4;$0}else i?$0+','+((i++==1)?'Date':dt):$0` - This is where most of the complicated logic resides:

  - If this is the 2nd line, then save the date string (`$4`) in `dt` and replace with the full matched string
  - else if `i` is not 0, then increment `i` and replace with the full matched string plus append string `',Date'` the first time, else append the `dt` value
  - else `i`=0, so replace with the original string.

Comment: you are the best. Thanks for this second help during a complicated week end, you saved the day twice. Brilliant !!!